# The counter should be reset to zero and then again should start from 1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to store the number of read messages in an array and then reset the counter based on the difference between length and counter value.

```
this.badgeCount = this.messages.length //5
```

Here **this.messages.length** is coming from the service for each message.

Whenever the matMenu is closed, I am resetting the counter to zero and mark the messages as read.

```
menuClosed(){
 this.badgeCount = 0;

 this.messages.forEach((message: Message){
  message.read = true;
 })

}
```

The problem here is **this.messages.length** is always going to be the actual length lets say **5** so whenever new message comes length becomes **6** in which case the badgeCount starts back at **6** instead of **0**.
Is there a way I can store the read messages in an array and then calculate it with the length of messages.

[Here is working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/closematbadgecounter)

Comment: why not use `this.badgeCount=this.messages.filter(x=>!x.read).length`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is just make the service count only **unread** messages like below

```
this.badgeCount = this.messages.filter((message: Message) {
    return !message.read;
}).length;
```

Comment: It just worked guys, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear but I will try to answer

If you want to keep read messages on a different array you can just declare it an add to it by using `push`

```
menuClosed(){
 this.badgeCount = 0;
 var readMessages : Message[];

 this.messages.forEach((message: Message){
  message.read = true;
  readMessages.push(message);
 })

 //now you can use readMessages.length 
}
```

If you dont need the read messages but just the counter of read messages...

```
menuClosed(){
 this.badgeCount = 0;

 this.messages.forEach((message: Message){
  message.read = true;
 })

 //keep the readMessages in a class variable and use it were needed
 this.readMessages = this.messages.length ;
}
```

Comment: seems more complex than just filtering the array

Comment: @JamieRees you understood what he need as ouput I literally offered him what he asked "Is there a way I can store the read messages in an array and then calculate it with the length of messages."